# Index and length must refer to a location with the string. Parameter name: length error

Tags: c#, substring, indexof

My program has been receiving this error recently and I am not sure why.  The code that is triggering it is:

```
foreach (var lot in item.LotNum.Split('|'))
{
    string vendor = string.Empty;
    if (lot.Trim().Contains("-"))
    vendor = lot.Trim().Substring(0, item.LotNum.IndexOf("-"));
}
```

LotNum = "br549 | BR549 | 570-PRIOR" and lot is "570-PRIOR" (without quotes) when the error triggers.  I've not used `IndexOf` before and so I am not sure what is wrong with the string that is being sent in.  I want to check for what causes the error beforehand because the exception is stopping the program and the bad data will be there for a while until it is fixed, and more may be added in the future.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `item.LotNum.IndexOf("-")` returns a number. When you crash, that number is greater than `variable.Length - 1`. That's what that exception means. Find out what `item.LotNum` is when you crash, and you'll see what went wrong.

Comment: Then `item.LotNum` has the `-` at a different position than `variable`. Did you mean `variable.Trim().Substring(0, variable.IndexOf("-"));`?

Comment: Well... what is the value of `item.LotNum`? You say that `variable` is `"570-PRIOR"`, but we need both

Comment: you should probably check both `item` and `LotNum` for null

Comment: @ps2goat that's not a `null`-related exception

Comment: no, but it's not a bad practice, either.

Comment: I added the full code section and what Lot Number equals to on the question.

Comment: Read the documentation for IndexOf. Google it and read it. It says that this will happen when you pass it those arguments. Not having used the method is no excuse for not bothering to read the documentation; quite the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New answer according your code update:

```
var lots = item.LotNum.Split('|');
foreach (var lot in lots)
{
    string vendor = string.Empty;
    if (lot.Contains("-"))
     vendor = lot.Substring(0, lot.IndexOf("-")).Trim();
}
```

Again, you were using IndexOf for a variable different than the one you want to get a substring

Comment: So if there is a space in the front, the Trim() being at the end won't mess it up from reading the substring in the correct position?

Comment: No, because this code is trimming the substring.

Comment: Sorry it took so long, but the program has to run through a lot of data (over an hours worth most of the time).  This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are using IndexOf for a variable different than the one you want to get a substring, so, the index will be out of range.

Try with: *edited*

```
variable = variable.Trim();
int index = variable.IndexOf("-");
if (index > 0)
 variable.Substring(0, index);
```

Comment: Note: it is also a bad idea to mix trim in this way; `variable` could be `"                 foo-bar     "` - (lots of spaces before the foo)

Comment: Yes, you are right I will edit my answer

Comment: Also, `IndexOf` will return `-1` if the item is not found, which will throw an exception when passed to `Substring` as the Length.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it again.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to check for the existence of the character using `Contains`, and if it's found use the `IndexOf`, otherwise just use the `Length` of the string (and put `Trim` at the end to avoid issues with using the `Length` after trimming):

```
variable.Substring(0, variable.Contains('-')
    ? variable.IndexOf('-')
    : variable.Length)
    .Trim();
```